# How to Scale the Vertices of hole in Mesh In Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I am making the Game about Hole,

The Game Contains Hole in the Mesh and the Object fall from it. Like [Hole.io](https://hole-io.com/) game.
I have achieved that moving the Hole in the Mesh by the Vertices and the Hole is Relocating or Moving according to My Desire.
I am Moving the Hole By getting the vertices of the Hole in Mesh and then Move or relocate it in the Script given Below.
There are 2 Issue's About which I need help.

1- I cannot make the Hole Bigger or Smaller by the vertices of the Hole in mesh.
2- I cannot add more vertices in the Hole of the mesh.

Is there Anyone Who can help the Image and the Code for the mesh is Given Below

Image: [image]

```
public MeshFilter meshFilter;

public MeshCollider meshCollider;

public Vector2 moveLimits;

//Hole vertices radius from the hole's center
public float radius;

public Transform holeCenter;
public Transform rotatingCircle;

public float moveSpeed;

Mesh mesh;
List<int> holeVertices;
//hole vertices offsets from hole center
List<Vector3> offsets;
int holeVerticesCount;

float x, y;
Vector3 touch,
targetPos;


void Start()
{
    RotateCircleAnim();

    //Initializing lists
    holeVertices = new List<int>();
    offsets = new List<Vector3>();

    //get the meshFilter's mesh
    mesh = meshFilter.mesh;

    //Find Hole vertices on the mesh
    FindHoleVertices();
}

void RotateCircleAnim()
{
    rotatingCircle.DORotate(new Vector3(90f, 0f, -90f), .2f).SetEase(Ease.Linear).From(new Vector3(90f, 0f, 0f)).SetLoops(-1, LoopType.Incremental);
}

void Update()
{
    MoveHole();
    //Update hole vertices
    UpdateHoleVerticesPosition();

}

void MoveHole()
{
    x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    //lerp (smooth) movement
    touch = Vector3.Lerp(holeCenter.position, holeCenter.position + new Vector3(x, 0f, y), moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    targetPos = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(touch.x, -moveLimits.x, moveLimits.x), touch.y, Mathf.Clamp(touch.z, -moveLimits.y, moveLimits.y));

    holeCenter.position = targetPos;
}

void UpdateHoleVerticesPosition()
{
    //FindHoleVertices();
    //Move hole vertices
    Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;

    for (int i = 0; i < holeVerticesCount; i++)
    {
        vertices[holeVertices[i]] = holeCenter.position + offsets[i];
    }

    //update mesh vertices
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    //update meshFilter's mesh
    meshFilter.mesh = mesh;
    //update collider
    meshCollider.sharedMesh = mesh;
}

void FindHoleVertices()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mesh.vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        //Calculate distance between holeCenter & each Vertex

        float distance = Vector3.Distance(holeCenter.position, mesh.vertices[i]);
        
        if (distance < radius)
        {
            //this vertex belongs to the Hole
            holeVertices.Add(i);
            //offset: how far the Vertex from the HoleCenter
            offsets.Add(mesh.vertices[i] - holeCenter.position);
        }
    }

    //save hole vertices count
    holeVerticesCount = holeVertices.Count; 
}


//Visualize Hole vertices Radius in the Scene view
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(holeCenter.position, radius);
}
```

Comment: what happens if you scale the whole object?

Comment: when I scale the Hole Object it will do the thing but when I need to Make it Smaller It does not Fulfill the Functionality.
Moreover, If scaling up the hole in the Mesh is not Properly Round so I have to add the More vertices in mesh.

Comment: well with hole.io theres only a finite number of sizes the hole can be, have you considered just making holes of various sizes and scaling the last provided hole so you have a more pattern of actual hole, scaled hole, actual hole, scaled hole? or just making the big hole and scaling it down?

Comment: So the issue is that we Cannot scale the Hole in Mesh.

Comment: as I suggested if you scale the whole mesh the hole will be auto scaled with it..